# Stuck with this inequality as I don't know how to handle possible negative numerators.

Tags: inequality

My son has received this from school. Appeared to be an example of Cauchy-Schwarz to me, but then I have noticed not all numerators will be positive. Have tried to compare each fraction to its numerators - same problem. Multiplying things to get a common denominator looks like tedious and unpromising. Any hint which way or which equality should I use? Thank you!

Let's $x,y,z > 0$ and $x+y+z=1$. Prove that:
$\frac{3x-1}{1-x^2} + \frac{3y-1}{1-y^2} + \frac{3z-1}{1-z^2} \geq 0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to edit your question and add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help.

Comment: As it stands, there's a problem when $x$, $y$ or $z$ is equal to $1$, so I'd suggest forcing them to be $<1$ (or by changing the inequality itself in a way you're sure you don't divide by zero). Not a big deal though, don't worry! Otherwise, a good idea in this kind of situation is to try to put everything on the same denominator in the left side, that way you'll only have to worry about the numerator sign-wise.

Answer (score 1):

The numerators can be postive or negative, but they always sum to zero. So what you have is a weighted sum, of these numerators, where higher weight is placed on the positive numerators than the negative numerators.

To show this explicitly you can compare term by term to the sum where the denominators are replaced by $\frac{8}{9}$. We can see that
$$\frac{3x-1}{1-x^2}  \geq \frac{3x-1}{\frac{8}{9}}$$
because when $x>\frac{1}{3}$ the numerator is postive and the denominator is smaller than $\frac{8}{9}$, and when $x<\frac{1}{3}$ the numerator is negative and the denominator is larger than $\frac{8}{9}$.

A more general way is to use Chebyshev's sum inequality:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality

Assume without loss of generality that $x\geq y\geq z$. Then take the numerators $3x-1, 3y-1, 3z-1$ as the $a_n$ terms and $\frac{1}{1-x^2},\frac{1}{1-y^2},\frac{1}{1-z^2},$ as the $b_n$ terms.

Comment: Thank you! Chebyshev's inequality is spot on! Your answer is precisely what I hoped for.